# What is the [gradient-flows] tag for?

Tags: support, tagging

What is the [gradient-flows](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gradient-flows) tag for? It has no tag wiki. There are relatively few questions using this tag, and I'm not sure how they relate to each other.

Comment: I would expect Morse theory, see Guillemin and Pollack. That's not to say people would use it correctly.

Answer (score 5):

A lot of the questions are using it wrong. I'll re-tag and write up a tag wiki in a bit. Thanks for bringing it to our attention.

Answer (score 3):

If a tag is [good enough for Tao](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/tag/gradient-flow/), it's good enough for MSE.

Seriously: although I'm not a fan of tags named after mathematical *objects* (rather than areas), this one appears to be used correctly: for dynamical systems of the kind $\dot x=-\nabla U(x)$, where $x$ can be a vector, or a function, or a point on manifold, or a manifold itself... There is a certain common theme here, although   the problems come from several fields: PDE, Riemannian geometry / geometric analysis, calculus of variations, some applied math (e.g. image processing).

Comment: Isn't it possible that a tag good enough for Terry Tao is _too good_ for MSE?